# `ldsNetwork.js` error when performing imperative APEX call

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, imperativeapex

I have a very strange issue with one of my imperative APEX call, I get the following error :

[image: Error]

Here is my calling code :

```js
const dto = {
       listId: this.selectedListId,
       name: currentlySelectedList.Name,
       usersIds: this.usersIds,
       skillsIds: this.skillsIds
}
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dto)));
const id = await saveCombinedList({dto: dto})
```

Here is my DTO :

```
public with sharing class SKILLS_Report_CombinedList_DTO {

    @AuraEnabled
    public Id listId { get; set; }

    @AuraEnabled
    public List<Id> usersIds {get;set;}

    @AuraEnabled
    public List<Id> skillsIds {get;set;}

    @AuraEnabled
    public String name {get;set;}

    public SKILLS_Report_CombinedList_DTO() {}
}
```

And my `@AuraEnabled` method :

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Id saveCombinedList(SKILLS_Report_CombinedList_DTO dto) {
    return service.saveCombinedList(dto);
}
```

And the look of my DTO before the call :

[image: DTO]

Do you have any clue about this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you check apex debug logs if it even made to the server side?